# From mathematics to neuroscience?

Tags: career-path, education, neuroscience

I'm a second-year mathematics undergraduate, and I am really interested in neuroscience and medicine. I would like to pursue a career in research or applications in the above mentioned field. I have heard of mathematics majors getting into theoretical and computational neuroscience, but I am more interested in biological neuroscience. I know that I would have to take courses in biology and neuroscience, but my school doesn't allow me take these courses, considering my major. I am already taking online courses in biology and neuroscience on YouTube and the likes, but I'm afraid that it won't be able to demonstrate proficiency in the subjects if I were to apply for a graduate degree.

So my question is, does anyone know of any paths I could follow, ultimately ending up in a career working in neuroscience and medicine (computational or biological, although biological is preferred)?

Thank you.

Comment: "my school doesn't allow me take these courses" It's only your second year. You can re-enter the university to study biology or neuroscience if you are really interested in them. Watching online courses is useless. You need to have lab experience. It's up to you to sacrifice two years to fulfill your dream. You'll need the two year math training for studying  any STEM fields in the future anyway.

Comment: Have you considered doing a master’s in Neuroscience / Cognitive Neuroscience after your undergraduate studies? They can be quite multidisciplinary and will help bring you up to speed on the needed topics. 
Are you planning to pursue a career in academia (and if so, do a PhD)?
In many European countries you need a master’s anyway to start a PhD. 
Which country are you in?

Comment: @leonos A masters degree program in neuroscience is going to assume fundamental knowledge in biology chemistry and physics.

Comment: @BryanKrause in general yes, but perhaps OP has some pre-university knowledge and validation of those topics. Also, there are exceptions, like this master’s in Cognitive sciences in Paris, which would be an ideal fit for a multidisciplinary candidate: https://cogmaster.ens.psl.eu/en/application/admissions-13494

Comment: @leonos The expectations for a masters program are likely to go well beyond pre-university knowledge. Probably at least 2 semesters of university physics, 4 of chemistry (general and organic, also biochem), and upper-division courses (not to mention their prereqs) in cell biology and genetics.

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't think it'll be plausible for me to start over considering the circumstances. But I think an interdisciplinary approach would be best, would most likely get into computational neuroscience.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Good luck; it seems your university or country does not really support an interdisciplinary approach if they limit the courses you're able to take so much.

Comment: If you have an interdisciplinary program in your school, you should take it, why ask us ?

Comment: @Nobody My school doesn't have the interdisciplinary program, I'd have to make the opportunity myself. And I asked primarily about transitioning into the more biological field of neuroscience. You don't have to comment if all you're going to do is complain. I didn't force you to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you are studying, but, given what you say, I'd guess that your shortest path to a career focusing on biological research is to start over and abandon the math degree (mathematician writing here, actually). In the US it is quite common for people to change fields between undergraduate and graduate study, but it seems a reach even here for this jump. I couldn't have done it (though long ago). I was required to take science in my math degree but it was all physics; no biology or chemistry. No graduate program in a biological field would likely consider me though I was at or near the top of my class then. Smart enough, but no background on which to move forward. All of the other students would be far ahead of me in the fundamentals.

Perhaps some of the coursework you have taken will apply in a new program (and would in the US), but it would likely save you only about a year in a new program.

Talk to an academic counsellor at your institution or a faculty member or two in math and in biology about where you are and where you want to go. It might even require changing institutions for the best path. Good luck.

Comment: (Non-biological) neuroscientist here. I would agree, as only a second-year (just started their second year?) math major, the best path forward would be switching wholesale to neuroscience

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Buffy. Seems like starting over is a popular opinion.

Comment: But I think I'll follow a more interdisciplinary approach since starting over isn't an option for me.